# using RedirectFromLoginPage on different pages

Tags: asp.net

Im using a login and a database to check if a user is in there then send the user to my "locked" page.
It workes nice and all but only from Default.aspx, but the user kan click around to other pages but the form is on all my pages until the user logs in.

How do i change this to work on all my pages, that includs when the user wants to log off:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="inloggad/rosta.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        </credentials>

      </forms>

    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the roles such as customer, admin and then add the following in your web.config.

```
<location path="/">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <allow roles="customers" />
         <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```